# How can I add clickable link in laTex? (\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv})

Tags: latex

How can I add clickable link in laTex? (\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv})

for example,

[image]

look at the image. I want that if someone clicks on GeeksforGeeks then it opens the GeeksforGeeks website.
How can I add that.

I used \href{link to the website}{GeeksforGeeeks}, but it is not working in altacv.

please consider \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}.

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: Thanks for editing, but can you please add a [mre], e.g. a small but compilable text document which we can use to reproduce your problem? Can you also link to where we can find `altacv.cls`, that's not available from ctan

Comment: Please read [this section of AltaCV documentation](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV#clickable-info-fields)!